# Does navNoReadFromCache really works?

Tags: caching, web, vb6, webbrowser-control

In vb6 web browser control i want to always read files freshly from web not from cache when i navigate. In [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag navNoReadFromCache is mentioned as not implemented. But in so many website it was mentioned like use it to prevent reading from cache. So is this really works? Please give explanation on this

Comment: Try adding a random parameter to the url -- that was it cannot be cached