# VB6 : Navigating to a webpage without reading files from temporary internet files folder

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, vb6, webbrowser-control

I am using VB6 web browser control. Every time I navigate(WebBrowser.Navigate) to a page I want the page to be loaded freshly from server instead of reading from cache and temporary internet files folder.I had posted a question related to issue [Does navNoReadFromCache really works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136680/does-navnoreadfromcache-really-works) and didnt get proper answers. Now I want to know is there any code or API available to open webbrowser without reading files from temporary internet files  and avoid cache reading. So please help me on this.

Comment: Refresh the page. Read the docs.

Comment: Try adding a query string parameter that is unique every time. For example, you could put a random number at the end of the query string which would cause you to get a new page instead of one from cache.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does navNoReadFromCache really works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136680/does-navnoreadfromcache-really-works)

Comment: @GMastros Hey G!  Good to know you're here.

Comment: @GMastros I didn't understand your solution? Where the random number need to be added? Give an example please

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw I don't think this question is duplicate. Now i want alternative for navNoReadFromCache . In my previous question i just asked whether that parameter really exists as microsoft mentioned that its not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to open (or shell out to) Internet Explorer, or if you choose to use the control packaged with VB6 you can force the browser not to rely on cached pages by appending a 'random' query string to the end, like so:

```
www.mysite.com?a=8267889457
```

```vb
Randomize Timer
Dim webAddress As String
webAddress = "www.mywebaddress.com?a=" & Int(Rnd(1)*1000000)
```

This should start the browser by requesting data directly from the server.

Also, you can include:

```
WebBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)
```

in your code to force a WebBrowser control to refresh itself.